# scrollToIndex() is not a function

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, carousel, react-native-flatlist

I have currently have a map and a carousel(similar to `FlatList`) and I want to be able to use `scrollToIndex` method of `FlatList` to snap to a certain item in the array. The issue is when I adopted the [react-native-snap-carousel](https://github.com/archriss/react-native-snap-carousel) library, which is based on `ScrollView`, I lost the ability to use the `scrollToIndex` method.  The ability to scroll to a certain index was working perfectly fine with `FlatList`.

I'm using a functional component so I'm using the `useRef` hook:

```js
    const flatListRef = useRef()
    const handleMarker = index => {
        flatListRef.current.scrollToIndex({ index, animated: true })
    }
```

I'm using `react-native-maps` for my map and the `handleMarker` above is so that when the user clicks on a marker on the map, the Carousel snaps to the pertaining item:

```js
<Marker
    key={marker.id}
    coordinate={{ latitude: marker.latitude, longitude: marker.longitude }}
    onPress={() => handleMarker(index)}
    ref={markerRef[index]}
>
</Marker>
```

Following is the Carousel that replaced `FlatList`:

```js
<Carousel
    data={items}
    renderItem={({ item }) => <Item item={item}/>}
    horizontal={true}
    ref={flatListRef}
    sliderWidth={width}
    sliderHeight={100}
    itemWidth={140}
    itemHeight={100}
/>
```

How do I achieve this this without `scrollToIndex`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use provided methods instead

```
const handleMarker = index => {
  flatListRef.current.snapToItem(index);    
}
```

Refs: https://github.com/archriss/react-native-snap-carousel/blob/master/doc/PROPS_METHODS_AND_GETTERS.md#available-methods

Comment: As of March 2022: flatListRef.snapToItem(index);